# .htaccess redirect urls ending with a symbol

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a url which has 4-5 characters after last slash and also has a `+` at the end of it.
(**Note:** the `+` symbol doesn't count in length)

I was able to make it work for 4-5 characters condition:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(index\.php)?\?id=([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,5}+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3?%4 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,5}+)/?$ someFile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm not able to make it work for the `+` symbol though i tried the condition `([0-9a-zA-Z\+]{4,5}+)` but doesn't work..also I think the condition `([0-9a-zA-Z\+]{4,5}+)` will still work if there is no `+` symbol at the end..

**Example:**

From:

```
http://example.com/1234+
```

To:

```
http://example.com/someFile.php?id=1234
```

**NOTE:** Redirect only if there is a `+` at the end.

Comment: What are example of those URLs ?

Comment: @anubhava see the comment on the answer for some reason i'm enable to include your username using `@` on the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` since it is a special regex symbol.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,5})\+?/?$ someFile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks mate didn't know that specifying the `+` symbol after the condition will work, thanks it's working. :)

Comment: Use this rule: **`RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,5})[+*]?/?$ someFile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55959/discussion-between-blo-and-anubhava).